# ElasticSearch version supported in Spring Data

Tags: elasticsearch, dependencies, version, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Spring Data ElasticSearch 1.3.2 release, which comes with ElasticSearch 1.5.2 by default. Is it possible to upgrade to the latest version of ES (2.0) without breaking the Spring Data ES repository API ?

Answer (score 1):

No. Due to several changes in the ES API this is not possible. Please see [DATAES-211](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-211) for details.

The current unstable working branch can be found here: [tree/DATAES-211-ES2.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/tree/DATAES-211-ES2.0)